# Javascript handling image loading - event.target.result is empty

Tags: javascript, canvas

Trying to separate image loading on canvas functionality. 
It works perfect like that

**html**

`<label>Image File:</label>
<br/>
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>`

**javascript**

```
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/influenztial/qy7h5/

But when I trying to separate it, it stucks because of `event.target.result` is becaming `undefind` for some reason.

Code is here

http://jsfiddle.net/qy7h5/1840/

Whats wrong? is there some best practice about that?

Comment: Please include minimal relevant code **in the question**

Comment: @JaromandaX okay , done

Comment: `reader.onload = (function(event) { onReaderLoad(event); })(e)` is the same as `reader.onload = onReaderLoad(e)` which is effectively (regarding the value of `reader.onload`) the same as `reader.onload = undefined`

Comment: @Andreasare you sure? because of problem not with reader, it doesnt event sas that its `undefined`
and even`reader.readAsDataURL` function is avalible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the code first right. Try my code which works fine.
Where I remove event cast and Image onload cast , also remove Image as argument which had been worked as event not image object.

```
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function handleImage(e) {
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function(event) {
  onReaderLoad(event);
 }
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
var onReaderLoad = function(event) {
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
 onImageLoad(image);
}

 image.src = event.target.result;
}

var onImageLoad = function(img) {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

I update fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikp72/qy7h5/1843/)

Comment: Oh, i get it now! Rarely used to code with pure js or even jquery.
In ExtJS I not even thinking about such stuff like tring to handle async functions in such way for some reason